# Error matches with concatenating string

Tags: java

Suppose you have a String

```
StringA = "a,b,c,d,e"
```

and want to find if StringA includes "a" and "c" at this specific order, first "a" and second( somewhere..) "c". For that i use

```
StringA.matches(".*" + "a" + ".*" + "c" +".*")
```

but with no results. Is there a syntax error;

Update: I provide the code I use

```
for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
    if (itinList.get(i).get(0).equals(username)) {

        itinList5.add(itinList.get(i));

        for (j =0; j < b; j++) {

        if(!itinList.get(j).get(0).equals(username) && itinList.get(j).get(18)
                .matches(".*?itinList.get(j).get(1).*?itinList.get(j).get(5).*")){
            itinList5.add(itinList.get(j));

        }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: if syntax error means missing semicolon then definitely yes

Comment: Try putting `itinList.get(j).get(18).matches(".*?itinList.get(j).get(1).*?itinList.get(j).get(5).*")` alone in an if statement. The other half of `&&` might be evaluating to false.

Comment: nothing changed putting the expression alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
if (stringA.matches(".*?a.*?c.*")) {
     //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile(".*?a,.*c.*?");
Matcher m=p.matcher(inp);
System.out.println(m.matches());
>> Above sysop will display true or false
```

Comment: I will try it Mohan but question remains.. why is my expression wrong?

Comment: .matches(".*?itinList.get(j).get(1).*?itinList.get(j).get(5).*")
>>itinList.get(j).get(1) and itinList.get(j).get(5) is inside " "  
which means it will not take variable values. Instead of that it will take that as string content.      System.out.println(StringA.matches(".*" + "a" + ".*" + "c" +".*"));
is working fine and it result true

Comment: As you can see on my post, the expression StringA.matches(".*" + "a" + ".*" + "c" +".*") doesn't work

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  String inp="a,b,c.e,f";
  System.out.println("Ouput="+inp.matches(".*" + "a" + ".*" + "c" +".*"));
}
I tested with this  program to validate  it results the output as  Ouput=true

Comment: johnnal please accept the answer if your problem is solved so that this question will not display in unaswered question section